# Formatting Issue in HTML messages from ResourceBundle using <s:actionerror/> or <s:actionmessage/> in Struts2

Tags: html, properties, struts2, resourcebundle, struts1

I have a properties file (resource bundle). I am trying to show errors in one of the jsp by loading them from properties file. I have an entry as below in my properties file.

> ```xml
> errors.password.rules=<font color="red">The password you have entered does not 
> meet password strength requirements.  Please select a new password that conforms 
> to the following standards:<UL><LI>Minimum length of 8 characters</LI>
> <LI>Maximum length of 18 characters</LI><LI>At least one upper-case character</LI>
> <LI>At least one lower-case character</LI><LI>At least one non-alphabetic character</LI>
> <LI>Does not contain 3 or more consecutive repeating characters (e.g. AAA)</LI>
> <LI>Does not contain the User ID</LI><LI>Does not contain common dictionary words 
> more than 4 characters long</LI><LI>New Password should not be the same as 
> previous password</LI></UL></font>
> ```

The above when loaded using struts 1 shows as below

> ```xml
> The password you have entered does not meet password strength requirements. 
> Please select a new password that conforms to the following standards:
> ```
>
> - Minimum length of 8 characters
> - Maximum length of 18 characters
> - At least one upper-case character
> - At least one lower-case character
> - At least one non-alphabetic character
> - Does not contain 3 or more consecutive repeating characters (e.g.    AAA)
> - Does not contain the User ID
> - Does not contain common dictionary words more than 4 characters long
> - New Password should not be the same as previous password

The same when loaded with Struts 2 shows see attached file for output

> ```xml
> • The password you have entered does not meet password strength requirements. 
>   Please select a new password that conforms to the following standards:
>
> o Minimum length of 8 characters 
> o Maximum length of 18 characters 
> o At least one upper-case character 
> o At least one lower-case character 
> o At least one non-alphabetic character 
> o Does not contain 3 or more consecutive repeating characters (e.g. AAA) 
> o Does not contain the User ID 
> o Does not contain common dictionary words more than 4 characters long 
> o New Password should not be the same as previous password
> ```

The above is displaying with the circled bullet, each in a next line. And for bullet is coming for first line

Please suggest what changes i have to do to my properties files to load the errors same as with struts 1.x.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: S2 puts the message inside another ul/li, hence the difference in <li> rendering

Answer (score 0):

The `<s:actionerror/>` and `<s:actionmessage/>` tags will encapsulate your `actionerrors` and  `actionmessages` in `<ul><li><span>yourmessage</span></li></ul>`.

This will make your message starting with a circle dot (because it is inside an `<li>`) and the other nested `<li>` with the circle outline (as defined by HTML for second-level `<li>`).

This:

```xml
<s:actionmessage />
```

will generate:

```html
<ul class="actionMessage"><li><span>

    <font color="red">The password you have entered does not 
    meet password strength requirements.  Please select a new password that conforms 
    to the following standards:<UL><LI>Minimum length of 8 characters</LI>
    <LI>Maximum length of 18 characters</LI><LI>At least one upper-case character</LI>
    <LI>At least one lower-case character</LI><LI>At least one non-alphabetic character</LI>
    <LI>Does not contain 3 or more consecutive repeating characters (e.g. AAA)</LI>
    <LI>Does not contain the User ID</LI><LI>Does not contain common dictionary words 
    more than 4 characters long</LI><LI>New Password should not be the same as 
    previous password</LI></UL></font>

</span></li></ul>
```

To generate the output you want, you can write your own .ftl, or more easily avoid using the `<s:actionerror/>` / `<s:actionmessage>` tags, and do the loop by yourself:

```xml
<s:if test="actionMessages!=null && actionMessages.size > 0">
    <div class="actionmessage">
        <s:iterator value="actionMessages" >
            <span>
                <s:property escapeHtml = "false" />
            </span>
            <br/>
        </s:iterator>
    </div>
</s:if>
```

result:

```html
<div class="actionmessage"><span>

    <font color="red">The password you have entered does not 
    meet password strength requirements.  Please select a new password that conforms 
    to the following standards:<UL><LI>Minimum length of 8 characters</LI>
    <LI>Maximum length of 18 characters</LI><LI>At least one upper-case character</LI>
    <LI>At least one lower-case character</LI><LI>At least one non-alphabetic character</LI>
    <LI>Does not contain 3 or more consecutive repeating characters (e.g. AAA)</LI>
    <LI>Does not contain the User ID</LI><LI>Does not contain common dictionary words 
    more than 4 characters long</LI><LI>New Password should not be the same as 
    previous password</LI></UL></font>

</span><br/></div>
```

You can do the loop for `actionMessages`, `actionErrors` and eventually `fieldErrors` and put them in a `messages.jsp` snippet, so you can use it in every page (without rewriting it every time) with something like:

```xml
<s:include value="/WEB-INF/content/fragments/messages.jsp" />
```