# How to print a Struts2 ActionMessage in a JavaScript alert box

Tags: java, javascript, html, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have one `Action` class which is sending an action message using `addActionMessage();`.

I want to display that message in my JSP using a JavaScript alert box.

I've tried with

```
alert  ('<s:actionmessage/>');
```

but it is showing `unterminated string literal`.

Comment: alert (' < s: actionmessage /> ') you can do that with the / terminator:

Comment: I am using this alert (' < s: actionmessage /> ').. But same error..

Answer (score 1):

The `<s:actionmessage/>` tag [generates an HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27862015/1654265) like the following:

```xml
<ul class="actionMessage">
    <li>
        <span>
            Your Message 1
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
            Your Message 2, and so on...
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This will break your javascript function with invalid JS code:

```
alert('<ul class="actionMessage">
        <li>
      ... 
     ');
```

The solution is to manually iterate over your messages, and build the output by yourself, with `<s:property/>`, instead of using `<s:actionmessage/>`:

```xml
<s:if test="actionMessages!=null && actionMessages.size > 0">
    <script>
        var actionMessages;
        <s:iterator value="actionMessages" >
            // Iterate the messages, and build the JS String
            actionMessages += '-' + '<s:property />' + '\n';
        </s:iterator>        
        alert (actionMessages);
    </script>
</s:if>
```

Also remember to wrap the single quotes from your actionMessages.