# Custom Tag for displaying struts2 Errors

Tags: struts2, custom-tags

I'm migrating struts1 to struts2 project and I'm facing an issue where we have extended the org.apache.struts.taglib.html.ErrorsTag class and overridden the doStartTag method.
In it we got the errors like this:

```
errors = RequestUtils.getActionErrors(this.pageContext, this.name);
```

We then write a javascript alert which lists the errors.
finally we write the result like this:

```
ResponseUtils.write(this.pageContext, results.toString() );
```

Now, in order to achieve this in struts2, I found that I should extend org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.ActionErrorTag and override the doStartTag method. 
Now i'm faced with a couple of issues:

1. I'm not sure how I can get the list of ActionErrors.
   I looked into the source of ActionErrorTag and saw they use

   ActionError error = (ActionError) component;

But this will only give me one error won't it?

2. What do I use to replace

   RequestUtils.present // to check if a message key exists

   RequestUtils.message // to write a message

   RequestUtils.saveException ()

   ResponseUtils.write?

Edit:

I see I can use what is suggested here :
[How to print a Struts2 ActionMessage in a JavaScript alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788779/how-to-print-a-struts2-actionmessage-in-a-javascript-alert-box/29793896#29793896)
But then I would have to go through each jsp that uses our custom tag and change it to this, how can I alter our tag to display the errors in an alert message?

Thanks

Comment: Just iterate errors in JSP and call js alert.

Comment: Thanks @AleksandrM for you sugesstion, please see my edit which addresses you sugesstion.

Comment: Take a look at S2 `ActionError` - https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/components/ActionError.java.